# Create Update function to take data from unique assignment sheet and populate results to each student

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

#### Purpose: Track Manitoba Education Outcomes for a Grade/Subject

Each student has a sheet which is named their full name; each assignment  has a sheet with filtered outcomes and populated with students.
Outcomes (116 for English broken down into 5 categories `GOC1..GOC5` Teacher's filter for the outcomes they are tracking for a particular assignment.
Need to get and paste (values only) into each student's individual sheet a) Title of assignment (C1) to StudentName!B4 (4 should be lastRow) b) Student name (D7) entire array (D7:AI7) - array? c) Outcome averages from individual assignment are located in (`d2:d6`) {Entire outcomes (`d2:ai6`)} to `StudentName!C4:G4` (4 should be lastRow)
Then go back to the assignment and do it again for the next student.

I have attempted `map()`, `copyValuesTo()`, `setValues()`. Pastes 1 value across the 5 GOCs. Struggling to get the student's name (sheet name for each student) to go into `getSheetByName()`. Also created arrays of data, named ranges for each `d2:d6` which clears itself then creates new named ranges for new assignment.  I was thinking this would help as those ranges never change but the assignment does.

```js
//Purpose: Track Manitoba Education Outcomes for a Grade/Subject
//Each student has a sheet which is named their full name; each assignment  has a sheet with filtered outcomes and populated with students
//Outcomes (116 for English broken down into 5 categories GOC1..GOC5 Teacher's filter for the outcomes they are tracking for a particular assignment
//Need to get and paste (values only) into each student's individual sheet a) Title of assignment (C1) to StudentName!B4 (4 should be lastRow) b) Student name (D7) entire array (D7:AI7) - array? c) Outcome averages from individual assignment are located in (d2:d6) {Entire outcomes (d2:ai6)} to StudentName!C4:G4 (4 should be lastRow)
//Then go back to the assignment and do it again for the next student.
//I have attempted map, copyvaluesto, setvalues. Pastes 1 value across the 5 GOCs
//Struggling to get the student's name (sheet name for each student) to go into getSheetByName
//Also created arrays of data, named ranges for each d2:d6 which clears itself then creates new named ranges for new assignment.  I was thinking this would help as those ranges never change but the assignment does.
function goArrayAssignment() {
  //trying to take val from assign. and put into 1 student, then for loop
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("StudentName").getRange("C4:G4"); //need lastrow?

  var dArray = source.getRange("d2:d6").getValues().flat().toString(); //   [3.0, , 3.0, , ] //use for loop?
  Logger.log(dArray);
  destination.setValue(dArray[0][0]); //outputs data but always 1st pos. of array
}

//Did I macro From Spelling unit assignment to Jeff Hiebert
function updateInfoMacro() {   //Macro of what I want to do.  Need to var assignName, studentName(Row7 of assignment)
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(-5, -2).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jeff Hiebert'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Spelling Test - Unit 23\'!D2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Spelling Test - Unit 23'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jeff Hiebert'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Spelling Test - Unit 23\'!D3').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 1).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Spelling Test - Unit 23'), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 0).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jeff Hiebert'), true);
```

Comment: I can share Google sheet if you send me your email address as our school division has restricted to added people only.

Comment: If would be possible to share  a google sheet with sample data and press [edit] for showing the current and desired results.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gfuJClPf732gAOLuXjma097mINNbIMIrglcOue6luCw/edit?usp=sharing    
No real data.  Student are my dog and myself.  Desired result is once filtered outcomes have been completed on an assignment (Spelling assign), I click UPDATE button and each student gets Assignment title, Score from D2:d6 copied to student's sheet (Their name is D7), then loop it and do the same the next student E2:E6 - Name is E7